# Residue field of a ring does not depend upon the maximal ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and let $A$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-algebra. We will say that $A$ is residually $\mathbb{K}$ if for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ we have that the structural morphism  $\mathbb{K} \to {A}/{\mathfrak{m}}$ coming from the $\mathbb{K}$-algebra structure of $A$ is an isomorphism

(Of course this definition is not very interesting when $A$ is a local ring….)

For example:

1. The Hilbert Nullstellensatz says that every finitely generated algebra over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{K}$ is residually $\mathbb{K}$.
2. If $X$ is a compact topological space then the ring of continuous functions $X \to \mathbb{R}$ is residually $\mathbb{R}$.

On can also view this definition geometrically: If $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ then $A$ is residually $\mathbb{K}$ iff every closed point of $X$ is $\mathbb{K}$-rational.

My question is: Is there any classification of residually $\mathbb{K}$ rings? (Or any partial result on the concept.)

Comment: I think the property you mean to ask about is not just that $A/\mathfrak{m}$ is abstractly isomorphic to $\mathbb{K}$ as a ring, but that the structural morphism $\mathbb{K} \to A/\mathfrak{m}$ coming from the $\mathbb{K}$-algebra structure of $A$ is an isomorphism. (In algebraic-geometric terminology, the degree of every closed point of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is $1$.) You should maybe make this clearer.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, for any abstract isomorphism $A/\mathfrak m \to \mathbb K$, don't we have that $\mathbb K \to A/\mathfrak m \to \mathbb K$ is a non-$0$ surjection, hence an isomorphism, so that $\mathbb K \to A/\mathfrak m$ is an isomorphism after all?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen You are right. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: (Actually I doubt my [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416564/residue-field-of-a-ring-does-not-depend-upon-the-maximal-ideal#comment1068831_416564); it is not clear that the composite map is a surjection.  EDIT:  @KConrad [pointed out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416564/residue-field-of-a-ring-does-not-depend-upon-the-maximal-ideal#comment1068839_416564) this issue a few seconds earlier.)

Comment: Another comment: if I'm not mistaken, if $A$ is any $$-algebra, and $S$ is the set of elements of $A$ that do not belong to any maximal ideal $$ such that $A/=$, then the localization $A[S^{-1}]$ (which removes every other maximal ideal) is a residually $$-ring, and the morphism $A \to A[S^{-1}]$ probably satisfies a universal property of some kind. So this gives a construction providing lots of examples. (The case of $=ℚ$ and $A=ℚ[t]$, for example, is intriguing: rational fraction whose denominator has no rational root.)

Comment: In view of Gro-Tsen's comment, one may ask whether such $\mathbb{K}$-algebras can be finitely generated.